# TSQL Converting rows into columns OR Grouping rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, sql-server-2012

I have to calculate shift hours of every staff member.

I have written a query that gets the data from our OLTP system and returns the date, staff and their login logout time. Login and logout times are two separate transactions in the system but I want login and logout time in a single row. See below image of what I get as input and what I want as an output. Kindly help write down a query to achieve my goal.

[image: Rows into columns]

Comment: _I have written a query that gets the data_ Maybe you should consider posting the queries that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is the `lag()` function, but that is not available in SQL Server 2008.  So, you can emulate it with a subquery:

```
      select i.day, i.staff, i.login,
             (select top 1 logout
              from input i2
              where i2.staff = i.staff and
                    i2.day = i.day and
                    i2.login = cast(login as date) and
                    i2.logout >= i.login
              order by i2.logout
             ) as LogOut
      from input i
      where logout = cast(logout as date)
```

The logic `logout = cast(logout as date)` is intended to identify the rows where `logout` has zero for the time components.

This assumes that none of the shift go over midnight.

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2012, you can use the same query.  Replacing it with the `lead()` is a bit of work:

```
      select day, staff, login, logout
      from (select i.day, i.staff, thedate as login, which,
                   lead(thedate) over (partition by staff, day order by date) as LogOut
            from (select i.day, i.staff,
                         (case when login = cast(login as date) then logout
                               else login
                          end) as thedate,
                         (case when login = cast(login as date) then 'logout'
                               else 'login'
                          end) as which
                  from input i
                 ) i
           ) i
      where which = 'login'
```

More subqueries are needed.  The problem is that you are comparing dates in two fields, so the innermost subquery puts them in one field (`'thedate'`).  The next finds the nextdate (which it assumes to be a logout when a row is a login, and the outermost just chooses the login rows.

To be honest, I think I prefer the first version with the subquery, given your data structure.

Comment: Gordon, i use SQL Server2012. Kindly modify the query and let me know how can i use lag function. thanks

Comment: @RizwanMalik Then why use the [tag:sql-server-2008] tag?

Comment: i have now tagged Sql server 2012. Can you please modify the query as the above query doesn't give any result

Comment: The `where which ...` clause is misplaced.

Comment: @AndriyM . . . Not exactly misplaced.  It has to be *after* (i.e. "outside") the `lead()`, so it does not affect the rows affected by the `lead()`.  However, it did cause a syntax error, because I forgot to include `which` in the subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it gives me an error. Can you modify the query?

Answer (score 0):

When I have to denormalize data, I like to use a self join. I've tested the below on SQL Server 2012. (However, the general approach should work with any SQL RDBS which support self joins but you'll have to modify the DATETIME2 datatype and function calls on a case-by-case basis.)

Data:

```
DECLARE @t1 AS TABLE (
    Day1 DATE
    ,Staff VARCHAR(3)
    ,Login DATETIME2
    ,Logout DATETIME2
);

INSERT INTO @t1
VALUES ('20130704', '123', '20130704 18:44:16.533', '20130704 00:00:00.000')
,('20130706', '456', '20130706 00:00:00.000', '20130706 01:10:12.000')
,('20130704', '123', '20130704 00:00:00.000', '20130704 20:24:16.553')
,('20130704', '123', '20130704 20:44:16.533', '20130704 00:00:00.000')
,('20130704', '123', '20130704 00:00:00.000', '20130704 22:54:16.553')
,('20130705', '456', '20130705 08:45:12.550', '20130705 00:00:00.000');
```

Solution:

```
SELECT a.Day1, a.Staff, a.Login, MIN(b.Logout) AS Logout, 
    DateDiff(minute, a.login, MIN(b.logout)) AS Elapsed
FROM @t1 a join @t1 b 
    ON a.Staff = b.Staff AND a.Login < b.Logout AND CONVERT(TIME, a.Login) > '00:00:00.00'
GROUP BY  a.Day1, a.Staff, a.Login;
```

Additional notes:

1. You mentioned you have to calculate the hours. This can be accomplished in the same query. The 'Elapsed' column calculates the minutes, in this case. (Change the first parameter of `DateDiff` to `hour` for your purpose.)

@Gordon Linoff

1. Query correctly handles situations if login is one day and logout is a different day.